# bot.login(token); Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am new to coding in Discord.js and I have a problem. writes to me the error is the line that contains bot.login(token);

Could you tell me my mistake and explain how to fix it? thank you in advance.

```
ReferenceError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'login')
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Neneng\a) Neneng_Pribadi File\2] Raynar abiyu 
diera\Raynar\Raynar (1)\Ray's MC\Discord BOT\index.js:34:9)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

here is the code itself:

```
https://pastebin.com/LVL4j6MU
```

Comment: Hello. Please not questions must be self-contained. The goal of SO is to build a database of questions & answer useful for other people. An external link that will be invalid in a few days does not achieve that :)

Comment: Which version of `discord.js` do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is a simple typo.

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed().
 
    bot.login(token);
```

That trailing period at the end of the first above line is causing your issue, as your code is now trying to do `new MessageEmbed().bot.login(token)` instead of just `bot.login(token)`. And obviously, there is no `bot` property on message embeds, which causes you to get your `undefined` error.

Replace the period with a semicolon, or remove it, and this error will be fixed.